# Given a sequence ${x_n}$ = $\sqrt(1)$ , $-\sqrt(1)$,$\sqrt(2)$,$-\sqrt(2)$...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence ${x_n}$ = $\sqrt{1}$ , $-\sqrt{1}$,$\sqrt{2}$,$-\sqrt{2}$...

If $y_n$ = {$x_1$ + $x_2$ + $x_3$ + $x_4$ + ... $x_n$}$1\over n $

Then sequence $y_n$  is

1.$Monotonic$

2.NOT bounded

3.bounded but not convergent (This is correct )

4.convergent

My attempt :I noticed a couple of things here

${x_n}$ is not convergent as two subsequences are convergent to different limits.

The terms of $y_n$ are $1$,$\sqrt(1)$/2,$\sqrt(2)$/3,

So ${y_n}$ seems to go to zero for large n and thus convergent ,but im not sure regd this . Can any1 help it out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $y_{2k}=0$, $y_{2k+1}=\sqrt{k+1}/(2k+1)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer .my carelessness . But i coudnt get expression for $a_{2k+1}$ ..terms are $y_1$ =$\sqrt(1)$/1 ,$y_3$=$\sqrt(2)$/3 ..

Comment: @SophieClad Have you checked it for initial naturals? If $y_{2k}=0$, $y_{2k+1}$ is the next positive $x_n$ divided by $n$.

Comment: Yes i have seen pattern of odd terms but coudnt get to general expression . Also as per ur formulae if i take limit of odd terms subsequence it goes to 0 .so both subsequences are converging to zero  . Am i right ?

Comment: @SophieClad Yes it is convergent. It is safer to say: because it is majorizes by $c\sqrt{n}$, but your idea is correct. But I am worried, that 3. is suggestet to be a correct answer. Impossible, if the current formulation of the question is correct.

Comment: can u tell me how u have come upto expression of odd terms ? and u say it s majorizes by c sqrtn .wat do u mean by this ?. i just took limit of odd term general expression and it ges to zero ,isn't that good enough ?

Comment: @SophieClad 1. $x_1+\dots+x_{2k}=0$, hence $x_1+\dots+x_{2k}+x_{2k+1}=x_{2k+1}=\sqrt{k+1}$. 2. I was only afraid, that you are assuming only sequence of odd or even terms. In the currenct formulation it is enough. :-)

Comment: Pls see my first comment . cant we get general expression of odd terms from there ?thnx

Comment: @SophieClad I understood, that you don't see, how to obtain them. If you see, there is nothing to do more.